# Method calling with {} before the ()... what's the name of this calling, what is this {}'s terminology

Tags: solidity, payable

```
   
 function setXTransferETH(address otherContract, uint256 x) payable external{
        OtherContract(otherContract).setX{value: msg.value}(x);
    }
```

As above method, the calling with {} before the ()... what's the name of this calling, what is this {}'s terminology?

(Sorry I come from C / Jave world, I do understand what this method does. But what's the syntax for this thing? )

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called [call-argument-list](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/grammar.html#a4.SolidityParser.callArgumentList) syntax.

It is useful to pass 'configuration' data to a function call, like the gas, value, etc.

In older versions of Solidity, the syntax to set the gas, value, etc., in a function like `.call`, was something like this:

```js
recipient.call.gas(3000).value(1 eth);
```

But that syntax is not supported any more in newer versions of Solidity.

The new syntax is like this:

```js
recipient.call{gas: 3000, value: 1 eth}();
```